# Apply style on first n columns of a row in .xls using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, formatting, apache-poi

I am using POI for excel creation in java and having trouble setting styles on the table created.

As the table data is huge, setting style on each and every individual cell is consuming time. And when i use rowstyle, the styling happens on those columns outside the table as well. Is there a way to apply styling on limited columns (say first n columns) of each row in an efficient way?

```
public XSSFWorkbook createReport(XSSFWorkbook wb, Map<String, List<ReportDto>> sheetData){
    int rowIndex = 1;
    int columnIndex = 0;
    int index = 1;
    wb.getSheetAt(0);
    XSSFRow tempRow;
    XSSFCell tempCell;
    wb.getSheetAt(0);

    for (String hexa : sheetData.keySet()) {
        List<COAReportSheet2Dto> itemList = sheetData.get(hexa);
        ListIterator<COAReportSheet2Dto> itemIterator = itemList.listIterator();
        while (itemIterator.hasNext()) {
            COAReportSheet2Dto eachItemData = itemIterator.next();
            if (!eachItemData.getGeneSymbol().equals("")) {
                tempRow = wb.getSheetAt(0).createRow(rowIndex++);

                tempCell = tempRow.createCell(columnIndex++);
                tempCell.setCellValue(index++);

                tempCell = tempRow.createCell(columnIndex++);
                tempCell.setCellValue(eachItemData.getPosition());

                tempCell = tempRow.createCell(columnIndex++);
                tempCell.setCellValue(eachItemData.getSymbol());

                tempCell = tempRow.createCell(columnIndex++);
                tempCell.setCellValue(hexa);

                tempCell = tempRow.createCell(columnIndex++);
                tempCell.setCellValue(eachItemData.getViperId);

                tempCell = tempRow.createCell(columnIndex);
                tempCell.setCellValue(eachItemData.getViperPole);
            }
            columnIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    return wb;
}
```

Comment: Could you please share in the question how you are coding? Otherwise I can't give you a properly answer.

Comment: @FagnerFonseca i've attached the code snippet. The formatting for entries in the outer loop have to be different but when i set row styling, it set styles on all the columns of that row although i want the formatting (like border) on just the 6 columns.

Comment: Where are you setting the CellStyle?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you are doing this, but you can do this:

```
public static XSSFWorkbook createReport(XSSFWorkbook wb, Map<String, List<COAReportSheet2Dto>> sheetData){
    int rowIndex = 1;
    int columnIndex = 0;
    int index = 1;
    wb.getSheetAt(0);
    XSSFRow tempRow;
    XSSFCell tempCell;
    wb.getSheetAt(0);

    // Create style
    CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

    for (String hexa : sheetData.keySet()) {
        List<COAReportSheet2Dto> itemList = sheetData.get(hexa);
        ListIterator<COAReportSheet2Dto> itemIterator = itemList.listIterator();
        while (itemIterator.hasNext()) {
            COAReportSheet2Dto eachItemData = itemIterator.next();
            if (!eachItemData.getGeneSymbol().equals("")) {
                tempRow = wb.getSheetAt(0).createRow(rowIndex++);

                tempCell = tempRow.createCell(columnIndex++);
                tempCell.setCellValue(index++);
                tempCell.setCellStyle(style); // style is set only on this column

                tempCell = tempRow.createCell(columnIndex++);
                tempCell.setCellValue(eachItemData.getPosition());

                tempCell = tempRow.createCell(columnIndex++);
                tempCell.setCellValue(eachItemData.getSymbol());

                tempCell = tempRow.createCell(columnIndex++);
                tempCell.setCellValue(hexa);

                tempCell = tempRow.createCell(columnIndex++);
                tempCell.setCellValue(eachItemData.getViperId());

                tempCell = tempRow.createCell(columnIndex);
                tempCell.setCellValue(eachItemData.getViperPole());
            }
            columnIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    return wb;
}
```

I'm creating the CellStyle in this way:

```
CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
```

Then you can set the style only in the columns you want. About the performance, remember to create the `CellStyle` only once. This way you can set the same `CellStyle` in every cell you want. If you create a new `CellStyle` for each Cell you create, your program can consume unnecessary memory.

Another way to do that is to use the `setDefaultColumnStyle` from `Sheet`:

```
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(0, style);
sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(1, style);
```

Comment: Thanks Fagner! I was setting the style after each tempCell.setCellValue but for huge data, the program was taking 2-3min to generate the .xls. I was hoping that setting style at row level will improve performance. I have another method that generates sheet having around 13 columns and that takes around 9-10 min with cell style set at cell level.

Comment: For large data you can use the SXSSFWorkbook. https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html

Comment: Thanks again and i'l try SXXSFWorkbook. So to style limited columns of the row, the only option would be to go with styling on individual cells, right?

Comment: You can use the `setDefaultColumnStyle` from Sheet, I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Yes, i did try this but requirement is to style specific columns of each row whereas setDefaultColumnStyle will set style on all the column outside the table as well.

Comment: In this case, I don't know if there is another way to do what you want otherwise set style at the cell level

Comment: Thanks @fagner for the help!